# How accurate is the Callendar-Van Dusen equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, measurements

... over 0 degC to 100 degC?
The equation itself can be found [here](http://www.thermibel.be/documents/pt100/pt100-equations.xml?lang=en)

I can do a very accurate one point calibration of a [1/10 DIN PT100](http://www.temperature.com.au/Support/RTDSensors/RTDaccuracyClassAClassB13DIN110DIN.aspx) sensor at 0 degC. If I use the equation to correct for non-linear resistance changes how accurate can I get it at 100 degC?

Comment: One could compare the tabulated RTD resistance values with the equation over the temperature range of interest to you. As far as accuracy goes, the Callendar-Van Dusen equation is not based on fundamental physics - it just added enough terms to make a polynomial that worked pretty well.

Comment: The problem being is that I want milliKelvin accuracy and have nothing to calibrate against that doesn't cost a fortune, except ice. And in case someone suggests Gallium, while it isn't especially toxic it has other nightmare properties.

Comment: Yes, gallium would be ugly and fatal to anything aluminum. Boiling water is possible, with some compensation for actual atmospheric pressure.  It seems to me, though, that you want to buy calibrated transducers (with NIST traceable documentation) rather than calibrating your own (yes, they cost more, but they have demonstrated performance).

Comment: How can you do a one point calibration of an equation with 3 (or 2 if you use the simpler form) parameters?

Comment: I have a 1/10 DIN PT100. I can do a one point calibration to remove offset at that point, thereby increasing accuracy. I also have generic parameters for the equation. How much better does using it improve accuracy/linearity?